# My computer needs 30 seconds to start

Tags: restart

My Mac is 7 years old, he had many problems to run normally.

I installed in it Ubuntu and the results are very good so I dont regret my choice.

But I think that I may have a little problem which is that Ubuntu needs 30 seconds to restart, it seems unusual. Is it?

Comment: In those days, I remember, windows took more than one minute to boot...

Answer (score 2):

30 seconds isn't slow at all, especially for a 7-year-old computer. I don't know why you wouldn't be satisfied with it, since 20 seconds is the normal boot time for Ubuntu.